# Disclaimer in an academic paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have a question about a paper of mine, which is highly likely to be published. Do you think I could put the following disclaimer: "This paper gives the views of the author, and not necessarily the position of the...(name of university)"? 
If yes, where is the right place to put it? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is very common, especially for people who work at government research bodies or think tanks.  But you should ask your department.

Comment: Why do you think you need such a disclaimer? Does your university require it?

Comment: I don't think the university requires it, I have not encountered such a requirement anywhere. Maybe I should ask just to make sure...

Comment: I would recommend against including a disclaimer unless it is required (or maybe if you feel your paper will be unusually controversial).  Once you start including optional disclaimers, then consistency becomes an issue: if you ever leave out a disclaimer, are you implicitly asserting that this time you do represent the university?  Do you need to include a disclaimer in nearly every document or presentation for the rest of your life?  Instead, unless your university has special rules for this, I think you can take it for granted that you are speaking for yourself unless otherwise noted.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be fine. You should look a the most recent 1-2 volumes of the journal you most want to publish the paper in and copy the disclaimer wording and placement that is used there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry, I did not mention it is going to be a peer-reviewed electronic book, therefore I do not have previous editions as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it required in Theses, but not in peer-reviewed publications.

If the journal requires it, it would be mentioned in the guide for authors.

But if anyone cares, it would be the institution.

Check a couple publications from your institution or ask a senior author if they have done it before.